# No Issue with Getters and Setters in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

When I look in the iOS 5 developer library, it says that I must include accessor methods for each variable I create. However, when I input

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *userName;
```

However, I don't see any errors saying I need "getters" and "setters". Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get a message about needing "getters" and "setters", because when compiler "synthesizes" that property, those accessor methods are created for you. You don't have to worry about them. When the compiler encounters the `@synthesize` directive (and in Xcode 4.4, even that is no longer needed), your accessor methods will be created for you.

This is discussed in the Declared Properties section of Apple's [The Objective-C Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html).

As an aside, when you say that you saw something about the fact that you "must include accessor methods for each variable", I assume that you are talking about this being required within a particular context. It certainly isn't a general requirement of all variables in your iOS app. There are times where they're useful. And there are some iOS features for which they're required. But it's not a blanket rule.

Answer (score 2):

A new feature in Xcode 4.4 is that it synthesizes properties automatically if you don't it yourself as mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/00-Introduction/Introduction.html):

> The compiler automatically calls @synthesize by default for unimplemented @properties.

Comment: In detail, it is added as `@synthesize userName=_userName;` so you can also access it directly.

Comment: so should I implement the "setters" and "getters" myself?

Comment: Synthesising the property (`@synthesize userName;`) is optional, so you I prefer writing less code. As to implementing the getter and setter methods yourself (`- (String *)userName...`), it is also unnecessary unless you want to do more precessing in them.

Comment: @Anonymous181 The process of "synthesizing" a property actually creates the "setters" and "getters" for you. No, you don't have to implement these access methods yourself. Just synthesize the property (and as sch points out, in Xcode 4.4 or later, you don't even need to do that).